# Set Firefox scrollbar behavour to advance a single screen per click?

Tags: firefox, scrollbar

In Chromium (Version 49.0.2623.108 Ubuntu 16.04) when I click on the scrollbar it advances down one screen. In Firefox (Mozilla Firefox 46.0) it advances to the point the on the scrollbar where I clicked. This is a change that I noticed in the last day or so.

How do I set it back to the previous behavior that matches Chromium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To advance a single screen use a right click on the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

In `about:config` add new integer parameter `ui.scrollToClick` equals to `0`.

Found this solution on [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Ui.scrollToClick).